# difference between parent and sibling in squid's cache_peer directive

Tags: proxy, cache, squid

I want to know what differs in the following two lines:

```
cache_peer cache.myparent.example parent 3128 3130
cache_peer cache.sibling.example sibling 3128 3130
```

For you reference, [this](http://www.deckle.co.uk/squid-users-guide/squid-configuration-basics.html) says:

> If you have to use your Internet Service Provider's cache, you will
>   have to configure Squid to query that machine as a parent. Configuring
>   their cache as a sibling would probably return error pages for every
>   URL that they do not already have in their cache.

Answer (score 2):

Got it, if parents fail, parents will forward the request on behalf of the child, but if siblings fail, just a cache miss returned, no op.

This is the reference, it seems squid lost its glossary in its docs: http://artemisa.unicauca.edu.co/~dabravo/squid24s1/glossary.htm#sibling

Comment: I think for clarity, your first statement should say "If the parent does not hold a requested object, it will forward the request on behalf of the child" (from docs) as opposed to "make request on the child". Good docs though.

Comment: OK, I will improve the answer.